Summing linearly spaced points in trigonometric functions
Consider the sum of linearly spaced points in one cycle of a sine wave with arbitrary phase:
$$\sum_{x=t-n+1}^t \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n} +p) $$
When n is even, the result is always 0 as the points cancel each other out symmetrically:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=t-n+1}^t \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n} +p)
&= \sum_{x=t-n/2+1}^t \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}+p) + \sum_{x=t-n+1}^{t-n/2} \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}+p) \\
&= \sum_{x=t-n/2+1}^t \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}+p) + \sin(\frac{\tau(x-n/2)}{n}+p) \\
&= \sum_{x=t-n/2+1}^t \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}+p) + \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}-\pi+p) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
When n is odd, the result is also always 0 if $\frac{\tau}{n}|p$ as one of the points are 0 and the remaining points mirror each other:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=t-n+1}^t \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n} + \frac{\tau k}{n})
&= \sin(\frac{-\tau k}{n} + \frac{\tau k}{n}) + \sum_{x=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \bigg( \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}) + \sin(\frac{-\tau x}{n}) \bigg) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Does this still hold if n is odd and phase is arbitrary? If so, how can we prove it?

See "How can we sum up sin and cos series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"

Don't use $\tau$ for $2\pi$ without comment.

@Blue thanks :)

Answer based on the link provided by @Blue:
We can employ a trick where we multiply the summation by half of its frequency:
$$ \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\tau}{2n})} \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{\tau x}{n}+p) \sin(\frac{\tau}{2n}) $$
Which simplifies to:
$$ \frac{1}{2\sin(\frac{\tau}{2n})} \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \bigg( \cos(\frac{\tau x}{n} + p - \frac{\tau}{2n}) - \cos(\frac{\tau x}{n} + p + \frac{\tau}{2n}) \bigg) $$
Which cancels out to 0.
There is a more general form of this at How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression? where the frequency doesn't need to be a multiple of $\tau$
